# Trigger event on bootstrap modal load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a page that displays several items, when clicking on an item's title, it fetches content and displays it in a [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), content is fetched using href target  :

```
<div class="tile-title">
    <a href="/get/content" data-target="#ModalDetailPoi" data-toggle="modal" class="feed_item_summary">Title</a>
</div>
```

I would like to do something once the content is loaded, so I tried to use the events `loaded.bs.modal`, `show.bs.modal`, `shown.bs.modal` but they don't ever seem to be triggered :

```
jQuery('.feed_i').on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e){
    console.log('azer');
});
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
jQuery(document).on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e){
    console.log('azer');
});
```

usually the modals are added at the end of the document, and the events are not per se triggered on the events that opened the popup.